# Convergence of Series of Complex Numbers with Decreasing Modulo (non-zero imaginary part)

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers tending to zero. Show that for $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, $\theta$ not a multiple of $2\pi$, the series $\sum_{n\geq1} a_n e^{in \theta}$ converges.

Note this is clearly not the case if we remove the restriction on $\theta$: $a_n = 1/n$ is decreasing but the harmonic series diverges. Thus I suspect the trick is finding appropriately alternating series that sum to our series.

Applying De Moivre yields

$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n\geq1} a_n e^{in \theta} &=& \sum_{n\geq1} a_n (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)^n \\ &=& \sum_{n\geq1}a_n (\cos n \theta + i \sin n\theta).\end{eqnarray*}$

A sequence of complex numbers converges iff real and imaginary parts converge, so it suffices to show convergence for $\sum a_n \cos n \theta$ and $\sum a_n \sin n \theta$. Here, I am stuck:  do I look at subsequences? How do I exploit the alternating behaviour of the trig functions?

Comment: Ask Dirichlet how to prove it.

Comment: I see where you are going, but boundedness of e.g. $\cos n\theta$ is not immediately obvious to me (clearly does not hold for $\theta = 2\pi$). What exactly is it that gives me boundedness?

Comment: It's easier without the split in real and imaginary part. If $\theta$ is not a multiple of $2\pi$, what is $\sum_{n=1}^m e^{in\theta}$?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^m e^{in\theta} = e^{i\theta} \frac{1-e^{i(m+1)\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}}$?

Comment: One-off in the exponent, but that's not so important. Can you see that that is bounded independently of $m$?

Comment: Ah of course $m$ not $m+1$. Sorry, I'm not sure I can see it - is it bounded by $\frac{e^{i \theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}}$?

Comment: That's not a real number, generally. $e^{i\theta}$ has modulus $1$, so can be ignored for the bound. The denominator is fixed, independent of $m$. Can you give a bound for $\lvert 1 - e^{im\theta}\rvert$?

Comment: Ah I see. I'm thinking $|e^{i m \theta}| = |e^{i \theta}|^m = 1$, so $|1-e^{i m \theta}| < 2$?

Comment: Must be $\leqslant$, it can equal $2$ for some combinations of $m$ and $\theta$.

Comment: That's what I meant, sry. But brilliant, that solves it. Thanks! :)

Comment: @DanielFischer Is the condition $a_n \rightarrow 0$, just because the question intends to use Dirichlet test? Otherwise, by ratio test , since $a_n$  is decreasing, $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} e^{i\theta}|<1$ so the series converges without using anywhere the fact that $a_n \rightarrow 0$? (Sorry for the comment, I just stumbled across this question and was wondering why the extra condition)

Comment: @harlem Since $\lvert e^{in\theta}\rvert = 1$, the condition $a_n \to 0$ is necessary by the term test. The ratio test requires the existence of a $c < 1$ such that $\lvert a_{n+1}\rvert \leqslant c\cdot \lvert a_n\rvert$ for all large enough $n$, just $\bigl\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\bigr\rvert < 1$ is not enough.